# How can I filter first then show values in BI?

Tags: oracle-12c, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

As my title, I'm in this trouble. When I create a BI publisher report, it's show all of value, I just can filter after that.

Can someone tell me know how can I filter values before show it in BI publisher report?

Like I call a Store Procedure and parse parameters, and then It show values

Ex: EXEC schema.SPStudents(001,Chris,Smalling,18,etc,...);

Now I'm using Oracle 12c.

Thanks!

Comment: Which BI tool are you using?

Comment: @Vérace 
OBIEE 12c

Comment: Can you run any query direct through SQL*Plus or SQLDeveloper? You should provide here the details of your tables (as text - no screenshots) and the full text of your Stored Procedure.